# How do I run multiple Cucumber.js test scenarios on the one feature file?

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am new to Cucumber test and have set up an environment using Selenium Webdriver, Cucumber.js and node.js. I have been able to setup single tests fine, but am confused how to run multiple tests (everything I Google just has examples of single tests).

My .feature Gherkin file looks like:

```
Feature: Products Page
 
    Scenario: Check the featured products
        When we request the products page
        Then we should receive
            | productName | productSubtitle |
            | Product A   | Lorem ipsum     |
            | Product B   | Dolar sit amet  |


    Scenario: Check product prices
        When we request the products page
        Then the product prices should be
            | productName| discount | price |
            | Product X  | 5.50 | 5.95 |
            | Product Y  | 5.00 | 6.00 |
            | Product Z  | 6.00 | 7.50 |
```

And my steps .js file looks like:

```
const { When, Then, After } = require('cucumber');
const assert = require('assert');
const { Builder, By, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

When('we request the products page', async function () {
    this.driver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();

    this.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.tagName('h1')));

    await this.driver.get('https://www.some-website.com/products');
});

Then('we should receive', async function (dataTable) {
    var productElements = await this.driver.findElements(By.className('product-card--featured'));
    var expectations = dataTable.hashes();
    for (let i = 0; i < expectations.length; i++) {
        const productName = await productElements[i].findElement(By.className('product__title')).getText();
        assert.equal(productName, expectations[i].productName);

        const productSubtitle = await productElements[i].findElement(By.className('product__subtitle')).getText();
        assert.equal(productSubtitle, expectations[i].productSubtitle);
    }
});

Then('the product prices should be', async function (dataTable) {
    var productElements = await this.driver.findElements(By.className('product-card'));
    var expectations = dataTable.hashes();
    for (let i = 0; i < expectations.length; i++) {
        const productName = await productElements[i].findElement(By.className('product__title')).getText();
        assert.equal(productName, expectations[i].productName);

        const discount = await productElements[i].findElement(By.css('.product-card__discount-price')).getText();
        assert.equal(discount, expectations[i].discountRate);

        const price = await productElements[i].findElement(By.css('.product-card__price')).getText();
        assert.equal(price, expectations[i].compRate);
    }
});

After(async function() {
    this.driver.close();
});
```

If I comment out either of these `Then` functions, the test works.

I know I can make a new step file and paste the other test on it, but surely there's a way to combine multiple tests on the one file?

Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of some resources that tell me how to do this?